# Bootstrap Tags-Input is encoding the html symbols like "&" to &amp;

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using bootstrap tags-input plugin to show tags provided by users.
I have noticed that when a tag contains **&** it gets converted to **&amp;**

Now this happens when I am refreshing the tags-input after adding it via jQuery

```
jQuery("#txtKeywords").tagsinput('add', keyword);
jQuery('#txtKeywords').tagsinput('refresh'); //this is where it changes & to &amp;
```

Do I have to tweak the tags-input library or is there any other solution available

Comment: Maybe you can use this function?  encodeURIComponent(uri) not sure if it is helpfull .

Comment: So found that refresh was the main culprit. I simply commented it and things are fine now

Comment: Good to hear you fixed it:)